# Eclipse Workspace stuck running irrelevant and closed JAVA code

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently trying to run a Java Project in Eclipse called Person (2 classes: Person and Greeter). When I run the code it is trying to run a project that is not even open. I went into that project, edited the code so that there no errors, and went back into my current project called Person to run it and the same issue arose. Something is sticking me to this old code project and I can't run anything new. Even if I go into another project it still gives me errors on this other coding project, HelloGlobe, and I can't go on!!!

[image: Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your Run Configurations under the `Run -> Run Configurations...` menu. I suspect you have a configuration left from your old code.

Whenever you run a piece of code, Eclipse creates a Run Configuration for it. Then when you press the green run button again, it will use that configuration again. As you change your code and run different things, they will get added as new Run Configurations. However, old ones are never deleted, and it's not completely clear which configuration Eclipse will choose when you press the Run button - so it could be trying to run an old configuration that relates to your old code. The Run Configurations dialog will allow you to see all the configurations in your project and delete those that are no longer needed.

*An aside:* If you click the down arrow beside the Run button, you'll be able to pick which configuration to run from all the options. So you can run multiple programs from the same project, which can be useful. But you can only get rid of old ones through the dialog.

Comment: I deleted all of my run configurations and now I get a error that says "Unable to Launch - The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches. Thoughts?

Comment: If you're trying to run the `Greeter` class in the screenshot above, you're going to need a `public static void main` method in there. Otherwise I'm going to need more information about exactly what you're trying to run.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it doesn't matter what kind of code or errors I am making in my desired project, it is reading code from other previous projects. I have run about 20+ projects without an issue until now.

Comment: figured it out. There is a selection to Close Projects that I was not doing so apparently I had a large amount of open projects that caused the issue. Problem solved!

Comment: Write it up as a proper answer so it's easier for others to spot in the future!